# How to support TLS for Artifactory 4.x

Tags: security, ssl, artifactory, tls1.2

Artifactory 4.x currently does not support TLS. This compromises the integrity packages/artifacts that are pulled in for production builds/images. Additionally, any credentials used to authenticate to artifactory are vulnerable to exposure.

How can I redirect any request over port 80 to 443

Any help on how to achieve this, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifactory 4.x is usually running on Tomcat. So if you want to setup TLS you need to either configure Tomcat or put a reverse proxy in front of it.

See the following in the Artifactory 4.x User Guide:
[Configuring Apache](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF4X/Configuring+Apache)
[Configuring NGINX](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF4X/Configuring+NGINX)

HTH,
Yinon

Comment: Thanks, @yinon, will try that.

Comment: sure @JBaruch Implementation in progress will update.